# override less variable property/value with inline variable in jsp/html

Tags: css, less, lesscss-resources

I have a situation where I have to override the less variable property/value with inline variable written in jsp/html. I define few variable in main file (abc.less) as follows:

`@bodyColor: rgb(88,90,91);   // (#585a5b) grayish

@brandColor1: rgb(23,59,107);   // (#173b6b) dark`

and I write following ones in jsp/html for changing the color, I am using the same variables name as main file.

`@bodyColor: rgb(255,0,0);   // (#ff0000) redish

@brandColor1: rgb(204,204,204);   // (#cccccc) grayish`

but it is overriding the main file property, kindly let me know how it will works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you compiling the Less stylesheet into regular CSS?

Comment: @Blender, I am using brandColor1 variable in 20 styles in main file and want to replace their color at one go. If I do it via regular css I have to copy each and every styles and paste into my jsp/html. In jsp/html file I have to change the color of each style.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file with all the colors defined in it as `colors.less`

```
@bodyColor: rgb(255,0,0); // (#ff0000) redish
@brandColor1: rgb(204,204,204); // (#cccccc) grayish
```

then add the following statement at the top in all the other less files,

```
@import "colors.less";
```

This way there is not need to change the colors in all the files, instead you can just change it in the `colors.less` file and it will get updated in all the other places.

You can use the same method for defining and reusing styles, mixins and other variables.